# write a query that applies to an entire db instead of a table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-query-store

Is it possible to write a query that applies to an entire database as opposed to one table.

So instead of usin:

```
 select * from table_name where columnName = ?
```

Can I say select * db_tables from from db where the table contains the column A?

Is is possible?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sure can!

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME like '%A'
```

Comment: thanks for the help @zambonee...iv hit another wall if you could be on any help that would be great https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107078/query-returning-wrong-value

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do `SELECT * FROM` all the tables, but you can run a query aganist multiple tables using [other statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) in SQL.