# Query returning wrong value?

Tags: c#, sql

Thanks to the help Ive recieved from zambonee on [write a query that applies to an entire db instead of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46086616/write-a-query-that-applies-to-an-entire-db-instead-of-a-table)

Using EF i'm writing a query that returns the userId from the aspNet_Users table. Then Im using this ID to delete the records in membership, userINroles & users....However the userId the query is returning is the wrong value..and Im connected to the correct DB iv checked the connectionString and tested other data

```
    using (DEntities Context = DAOHelper.GetObjectContext<DEntities>())
{
Guid aspUserIdToRemove = Context.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>("Select UserId FROM aspnet_Users where UserName LIKE '%" + userName + "%'").ElementType.GUID;

string aspUserId = aspUserIdToRemove.ToString();
aspUserId = aspUserId.Replace("{", string.Empty);
aspUserId = aspUserId.Replace("}", string.Empty);

Context .ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM aspnet_Membership where UserId = '" + aspUserId + "'");
Context .ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM aspnet_UsersInRoles where UserId = '" + aspUserId + "'");
Context .ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM aspnet_Users where UserId = '" + aspUserId + "'");
```

aspUserIdToRemove returns {296afbff-1b0b-3ff5-9d6c-4e7e599f8b57} when it should return {31E62355-8AE2-4C44-A270-2F185581B742}...

{296afbff-1b0b-3ff5-9d6c-4e7e599f8b57}  doesnt even exist in the DB...does anyone have any idea whats wrong? thanks

Just to reinforce about being on the same DB im doing further delete commands on different tables and confirming that they are deleted

Following on from the comments -

```
var s = dnnEntitiesDbContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>("Select UserId FROM aspnet_Users where UserName LIKE '%" + userName + "%'");
```

s.elementtype.GUID holds the 296afbff-1b0b-3ff5-9d6c-4e7e599f8b57

but s.base.elementType.baseType.Guid returns a diff GUID '81c5f....
but no sign of the one I am looking

Comment: Just to clarify - does the statement "Select UserId FROM aspnet_Users where UserName LIKE '%" + userName + "%'" return the right GUID when run from the console?

Comment: yes when I run  Select UserId FROM aspnet_Users where UserName LIKE '%JimBob%' in SQL it returns 31E62355-8AE2-4C44-A270-2F185581B742

Comment: You're using EF incorrectly - you should avoid `ExecuteStoreQuery` and use the strongly-typed model-based API instead, and if you absolutely must use `ExecuteStoreQuery` then **USE PARAMETERISED QUERIES!** - your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Is it possible to just leave the GUID as a string value, rather than trying to turn it into a Guid type (which you then convert back to a string)?  I'm wondering if there is a problem with casting between strings and GUIDs between SQL and C#.

Comment: @Dai Im working on existing code created by another user I'm trying to fix a bug...

Comment: @meisen99 please see update on orignal Q. thanks for reply

Comment: Change the `LIKE %%` operator to an equality operator - I'm guessing you're using a username substring that matches multiple users - or you're set-up to allow non-unique usernames.

Comment: Ah - elementType is "string" and {296afbff-1b0b-3ff5-9d6c-4e7e599f8b57} is the GUID for a string.  What is "s"?

Comment: That is, does string aspUserIdToRemove = Context.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>("Select UserId FROM aspnet_Users where UserName LIKE '%" + userName + "%'"); return what you want?

Comment: @Dai ive added the domain the UN which is how they are stored 'BlackR\SodaBread123' this flags - Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '\'. why cant it search with a \?

Comment: @meisen99 I had to write string aspUserIdToRemove = dnnEntitiesDbContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>("Select UserId FROM aspnet_Users where UserName LIKE '%" + userName + "%'").ToString(); returns System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult`1[System.String]

Comment: @dai ive just tried this and it is return the wrong GUID value again...any ideas?

Comment: @John Run the query in SSMS and look at **all** the results - not just the first row. Get the query so it works in SSMS first before making trial-and-error changes to your program source code. And if you're meant to be doing exact-match searches don't use the `LIKE` operator.

Comment: the query works in SSMS it always has that was the firs thing I tested before posting a Q and there is only one result is the query

Answer (score 2):

You may have some misunderstanding about `ExecuteStoreQuery<T>`, it will return the `Type` you specified.  In your case, it will return `string` back.

```
Guid aspUserIdToRemove = Context.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>("Select UserId FROM aspnet_Users where UserName LIKE '%" + userName + "%'").ElementType.GUID;
```

With this statement, `ExecuteStoreQuery<string>` will return a `string` type of `UserId`, and then get the `GUID` from `ElementType`, but not `GUID` of *Users*

To solve that, you just need to use

```
string aspUserIdToRemove = Context.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>("Select UserId FROM aspnet_Users where UserName LIKE '%" + userName + "%'");
```

More better you may want to avoid SQL injection, and use parameter

```
string aspUserIdToRemove = Context.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>("Select UserId FROM aspnet_Users where UserName LIKE '%{0}%'", userName);
```

Details you can check the [API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208(v=vs.100).aspx)

As the `aspUserIdToRemove` is a string, you don't need to use `.ToString()` on it.  However, I don't have enough data, you may need to check do you need to escape the '{}'.

Moreover, from your comment, the `\` is an escape character, if you want to concat in a string, you need to escape that with `\\` ([API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx))