# why can't I use in a search query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

The username in the aspnet_users table is BlackR\johnBurns

I'm trying to write a query to get this record where username = but it is flagging

```
string username1 = @"BlackR\" + johnBurns;
var s = DbContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>("Select UserId FROM aspnet_Users where UserName = " + username1);
```

this fails saying `Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '\'.`

Does the @ not cancel this out? Is it because of its a SQL query?

Comment: Learn to use parameters rather than munging query strings.

Comment: an example please?

Comment: You forgot using single quotes to pass string variable `username1`, it should be `("Select UserId FROM aspnet_Users where UserName = '" + username1 + "'")`. Again, such hassle may be prevented by using parameterized query.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto you sir are too kind...have you perhaps seen my Original Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107078/query-returning-wrong-value

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto No NO **NO!** That is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I know that it's vulnerable to SQL injection, so I recommends parameterized query instead. I just point out how OP mistakenly using query string value concatenation without using single quotes.

Comment: It should be `"Select UserId FROM aspnet_Users where UserName = @UserName"` (All in the same string constant), and then also have a line like this: `var p = new SqlParamter("@UserName", @"BlackR\" + johnBurns);`  that you can pass as an additional argument to `ExecuteStoreQuery()`.

Answer (score -1):

Assume variable `johnBurns` store value `johnBurns`, then your code is similar to this:

```
string username1 = "BlackR\\johnBurns";
var s = DbContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>("Select UserId FROM aspnet_Users where UserName = BlackR\johnBurns");
```

The first line, `@` will lets you specify a string without having to escape any characters (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/429556/1050927))

The second line, compiler will try to find the escape character.  In this example, it will looking to `\j`, which is not a valid escape character.

You may find the escape character list here: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

And finally, you may need to add the *single quotes* for string parameter of SQL, and better to use [parameterized query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358769(v=vs.100).aspx) as `Tetsuya Yamamoto` suggested.
With parameterized query, you don't need to escape the special character, system will help you do that.

Comment: How `string username1 = @"BlackR\" + johnBurns;` will turn into `string username1 = "BlackR\\johnBurns";` is very confusing... And how it `\` disappears from second string is even stranger... (Obviously "use parametrized queries" is the answer - so you may want to delete first half of the post or fix it up).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The `\ ` will be escaped to `\\ `, is that equal to `@"BlackR\"`?  And of coz, I'm assume the `johnBurns` store the value `johnBurns`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I have edit the answer.  Meanwhile, I don't think the question is duplicate of the one you marked.  It can use `MySqlCommand`, or just continue with `ExecuteStoreQuery` with parameter ([Reference MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358769(v=vs.100).aspx))